# Do you need to do a damp test?

Tags: mold

I have mold smells coming from the various hole in my flat.  My landlord inspected the property and said we can't see it but are willing to cover all the cracks and holes for you.

I said you can't see it because it is inside the structure. I requested they do a damp test however they said since you have no visible or repeat mould growth that means it's no longer damp and all that remains is possibly toxins coming up through cracks and holes etc.  I did have a damp wall years ago but they sealed over it.

Is it ok to assume a damp test is not necessary since there hasn't been any repeat visible mould growth for years? And, is it ok to assume sealing cracks and holes would seal in any remaining toxins in the structure of the flat?

Some people might say regardless of damp or dried mould (i.e. toxins remaining) you should break the structure and clean the source, however most councils would not do that and it would be too much work for me/most people.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard for us to help you without more info (i.e. how strong is the odor, what other evidence of moisture do you have, where might the moisture be coming from, etc). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I don't know of any other evidence of moisture but thats the question, shouldn't they be using a damp meter to check or is it ok for them to dismiss on no visible mould.  As for the smell, it is strong and coming from holes in walls.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that thinks you can get rid of mold in a structure is selling you oceanfront property in the desert!
You can kill surface mold but wood products are full of mold, your best defense is to maintain dry walls and possibly dehumidify the living space.

Mold needs moisture, food and the correct temp to grow, just about everything organic is a food source, moisture a roof or pipe leak, if the temp is comfortable to you mold can live there.

The easiest method is take away the moisture, not enough moisture mold will go dormant. I do use hydrogen peroxide to reduce mold growth it kills surface mold quite well at 3% with water but allow a water leak and a piece of paper, sheetrock, carpet can be a home to a new mold colony very easily.

Now that we talked how prevalent mold is with thousands of species Not very many are toxic and some are good so unless you have a sample growing to send into a lab for analysis don’t worry about it.
If you think you are having health problems order a testing kit and get a sample analysis, until you do that you are possibly causing more harm to your self by worrying about it.